# Howto quickly configure some users for Shibboleth IdP

Tags: single-sign-on, shibboleth

I have a Django app that is the SP. Installed Shibboleth as IdP.

The SP redirects unauthorized users to Shibboleth IdP login page: This is where I'm stuck, I have no users/valid credentials for this login form.

How can I painlessly set some users credentials for this login form (best would be simply define a few users in some Shibboleth configuration file)?

**Edit1**

I am now trying to use the free LDAP service at `ldap.forumsys.com`
Unfortunately I cannot get that to work either.

The LDAP configuration is very complicated (`ldap-authn-config.xml`)
and when using the JAAS configuration (`jaas.config`)

```
ShibUserPassAuth {
    /*
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required;
    */

org.ldaptive.jaas.LdapLoginModule required
  ldapUrl="ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389"
  baseDn="ou=chemists,dc=example,dc=com"
  userFilter="uid={uid}";
};
```

Then I always get the message:

> The username you entered cannot be identified.

If anyone knows how to set this up correctly, I'd love some input. Otherwise I’ll post my final configuration, once I get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

noob guess, change this line:

```
userFilter="uid={uid}";
```

to this:

```
userFilter="uid={user}";
```